# To set a size in ElasticSearch using @Query

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jpql

I'm using @query to retrieve the elasticsearch data through JPQL. the default size is 10, i mentioned the size as 5 in @Query but am getting 10 records but i need 5 records.how to solve this problem

```
 @Query("\"from\":\"0\",\"size\":\"5\",{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"brand\":\"?0\"}}]}}}")
```

List findByBrand(String brand);

Comment: What if you give `from` and `size` as `int` without giving them as `string`, I mean without the quotes?

Comment: You can also try to run exact same query in elastic search and see what happens curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d' query string '

Comment: i have changed to int but still am facing the same issue. can i have code example?

Comment: Yeah its working fine in curl but i can't retrieve using @query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add a [`Pageable` argument](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) to your `findByBrand` method:

```
@Query("{\"bool\":{\"must\":[{\"term\":{\"brand\":\"?0\"}}]}}")
List findByBrand(String brand, Pageable pageable);
```

Then you can call that method like this:

```
List brands = findByBrand("mybrand", new PageRequest(0, 5));
```

Alternatively, you can also specify how many results you want in [the method name itself](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result):

```
List brands = findTop5ByBrand(String brand);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in that that @Query annotation.
Generates only "query" node.
You would expect to have query like that.

```
{
  "from": "0",
  "size": "5",
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "brand": "?0"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Because of this your are not able to put "from" and "size" in the query string. That's why in other answer you have to use Pageable to get the results.
The @Query string in the question is not a json string.
It misses "query": before "bool" to be proper json.